# Having a lot of [Ljava.lang.Object;@hashcode in reading arraylist content of object from file

Tags: java, arraylist, file-handling

I write Code objects which contains two property such as `String` and `ArrayList<Vector>` into text file. When i read them back from file arraylist property contains a lot of  [Ljava.lang.Object;@hashcode. But some arraylist don't have these.

*These are written into file:*

**gid** : g5, **code** : [[[7], [p, [8, 8, 8, 7, 7, 7], o, [2, 2, 1]]], [[1], [c, [6, 6, 5]]], [[9], [c, [5, 5]]], [[3], [n, [4, 4], c, [6, 6, 5]]], [[4], [[[n, 4]]]], [[5], [c, [6, 6, 6, 6, 5]]], [[6], [c, [6, 6]]]]

**gid** : g6, **code** : [[[10], [c, [13, 5]]], [[11], [n, [12, 12, 3, 3]]], [[12], [n, [3, 3]]], [[3], [c, [13, 13, 5, 5]]], [[5], [c, [13, 13, 13, 13, 6, 6, 6]]], [[13], [c, [6, 6, 6, 5, 5]]]]

*Read back from file are:*

**gid** : g5, **code** : [[[7], [p, [8, 2, 2, 1, 1, 1], o, [2, 6, 1]]], [[5], [c, [6, [Ljava.lang.Object;@1e44538, 5]]], [[9], [c, [4, 4]]], [[3], [n, [4, [Ljava.lang.Object;@17c760b], c, [[Ljava.lang.Object;@1e44538, [Ljava.lang.Object;@1e44538, 4]]], [[[Ljava.lang.Object;@17c760b], [[[[c, [6, 6, 6, 6, 6, 6, 6, 5]], [Ljava.lang.Object;@17c760b]]]], [[4], [[Ljava.lang.Object;@29d838, [[Ljava.lang.Object;@1e44538, [Ljava.lang.Object;@1e44538, [Ljava.lang.Object;@1e44538, [Ljava.lang.Object;@1e44538, 4]]], [[[Ljava.lang.Object;@1e44538], [[Ljava.lang.Object;@29d838, [[Ljava.lang.Object;@1e44538, [Ljava.lang.Object;@1e44538]]]]

**gid** : g6, **code** : [[[10], [c, [13, 5]]], [[11], [n, [12, [Ljava.lang.Object;@29d838, 3, n]]], [[[Ljava.lang.Object;@29d838], [[Ljava.lang.Object;@1327c02, [n, n]]], [[n], [c, [2, 2, c, c]]], [[c], [[n, 4], [2, 2, 2, 2, 6, [Ljava.lang.Object;@16b7f83, [Ljava.lang.Object;@16b7f83]]], [[2], [o, [[Ljava.lang.Object;@16b7f83, [Ljava.lang.Object;@16b7f83, [Ljava.lang.Object;@16b7f83, c, c]]]]

*Here is Code class.*

```
public class Codes implements Serializable{

public String gid;
public ArrayList<Vector> code;

public Codes()
{
    gid = "";
    code  = new ArrayList<Vector>();
}

Codes(String id,ArrayList c)
{
    gid = id;
    code = c;
}

public ArrayList<Vector> getCode()
{
    return code;
}

public String getId()
{
    return gid;
}

@Override
public String toString()
{
    return gid + " " + code;
}
```

*I write this object into a text file as follow:*

```
File f = new File("./CodesObj.txt");
    if(!f.exists()) {
        f.createNewFile();
        FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream(f);
        ObjectOutputStream os = new ObjectOutputStream(fos);
       try{
            System.out.println("gid : " + c.gid + ", code : " + c.code);
            os.writeObject(c);
         }catch (IOException e){
            e.printStackTrace();
         }
        os.flush();
        os.close();
      }
```

*This is how I read from file*

```
try{
     ois = new ObjectInputStream(new FileInputStream("./CodesObj.txt"));
     Codes obj = null;
    while( (obj = (Codes) ois.readObject()) != null){   
        if(obj instanceof Codes){
            System.out.println("gid : " + obj.gid + ", code : " + obj.code);    
        }
    }       
}catch (EOFException ex) {  
   } catch (ClassNotFoundException ex) {
       ex.printStackTrace();
   } catch (FileNotFoundException ex) {
       ex.printStackTrace();
   } catch (IOException ex) {
       ex.printStackTrace();
   } finally {
       //Close the ObjectInputStream
       try {
           if (ois != null) {
               ois.close();
           }
       } catch (IOException ex) {
           ex.printStackTrace();
       }
   }
```

Comment: where are you getting the problem in code?

Comment: Where do you set the ArrayList? due to the rawtype in the constructor you could pass an `ArrayList<Object>` to your class which could result in the Hashcode return since you didn´t overwrite `toString` if it would contain other Elements then a `Vector`

Comment: Why there are alot of [Ljava.lang.Object;@29d838 in code property when i read back from text file?

Comment: It would be helpful if you'd reduce this to a short but *complete* program demonstrating the problem. I would also strongly recommend against using a `.txt` extension for code written using `ObjectOutputStream`.

Comment: What *is* the *problem?* Are you aware that `[Ljava.lang.Object;@29d838` is just the result of calling `Object[].toString()`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
public ArrayList<Vector> code;
```

Clearly this is really

```
public ArrayList<Vector<Object[]>> code;
```

for at least some instances. You are printing the `ArrayList`, which calls `AbstractCollection.toString()`, which calls `Vector.toString()`, which calls `item.toString()` for each item. If the item is an `Object[]`, what you will get is the result of `Object[].toString()`, which calls `Object.toString(),` which produces strings of the general form

```
[Ljava.lang.Object;@hashcode
```

There's no easy solution to this. You'll have to provide an override as `Code.toString()` which walks the `ArrayList` items and their interior `Vectors` and call `Arrays.toString()` on each item of the `Vector.`

Answer (score 2):

One problem I noticed with your code is that you are trying to do a `System.out()` on an `ArrayList` which will result in strange things being displayed.

I created a helper method called `printList()` which accepts a `List` as input.  It iterates over this list, and converts each list element, which is a `Vector<Object[]>`, to a 2D array.  Then it uses `Arrays.deepToString()` to print out this 2D array.

```
public class Codes implements Serializable {
    public String gid;
    public ArrayList<Vector> code;

    // constructor and getters/setters

    @Override
    public String toString()
    {
        return gid + " " + printList(code);
    }

    private void printList(List list) {
        String listString = "[";

        for (int i=0; i < list.size(); ++i) {
            Vector v = list.get(i);
            Object[][] array = (Object[][])v.toArray(new Object[v.size()][]);

            if (i > 0) {
                listString += ", ";
            }

            listString += Arrays.deepToString(array);
        }
        listString += "]";

        return listString;
    }
}
```

I have tested this code locally on IntelliJ and it appears to be working.

Comment: I try this. but the problem is still exist:(

Comment: The part between `[]` is exactly what `ArrayList.toString()` already produces.

Comment: Still redundant. The real question here is what's in the `Vector`. Clearly it is `Object[]`.

Comment: Looks good, but you need to cater for both `Object[]` and `Object[][]`, as I now see to occur. And `Object[][][]`. Time for recursion again.

Comment: I was considering refactoring my answer a third time, but came upon an impasse when I realized that I knew of no easy way to detect what might be contained inside each `Vector` entry (e.g. `Object[]`, `Object[][]`, or even `Object[][][]`).  I think the OP should consider creating a data structure which is more amenable to iteration, rather than its current design.

Comment: I get Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0" java.lang.ArrayStoreException for the line of Object[][] array = (Object[][])v.toArray(new Object[v.size()][]);

Comment: Yeah...this won't work for your code because each `Vector` may have an `Object` array of arbitrary dimension.  I would recommend that you create a custom data structure over which you can easily iterate.

Comment: @Tim Biegeleisen  for code = [[[7], [p, [8, 8, 8, 7, 7, 7], o, [2, 2, 1]]], both of [7], and [p, [8, 8, 8, 7, 7, 7], o, [2, 2, 1]] are vectors. It is vector of vectors.

Comment: Rethink your design strategy.  It is difficult and error prone to be working with your current data structure.

Comment: You need another method,recursive, that prints `Object[]` arrays. But I agree entirely that the lack of fixed data structures is the real problem. @YuWaiHlaing I suggest you stop using object arrays completely, and `Vector` while you're at it, and just keep using nested `ArrayLists`. That way at least they can all print themselves.

Answer (score -1):

The problem is you're printing out the hashcode of the object when you're using `System.out.println()`

To print out the actual data inside of it, you should use an enhanced for loop.

`gid` prints out fine because it's a `String`, but `code`, which holds an `ArrayList` of `Vectors`, can't be printed out by doing `System.out.println(code)` (unless you want the hashcode, of course)

Do this instead if you want to print out all the vectors.

```
for(Vector vector : code){
   System.out.println(vector);
}
```

Comment: Yes it can. See [`AbstractCollection.toString()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/AbstractCollection.html#toString()). The problem here is what's in the `Vector.`